# "The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user." in dashboard

Tags: reporting, error-messages, dashboard

I am building a dashboard for my coworker in SF. However one of the reports in the dashboard is giving me the error "The source report is based on a report type that is inaccessible to the dashboard's running user." when I try to "View As" her.  I have made sure that her user profile has read access to the objects in her report. What could be causing this?